# 'GooglePlaces/GooglePlaces.h' file not found - undeclared kGMSAutocompleteMatchAttribute

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I am trying to Build an app from several years back that worked fine then, but now is giving an error as GooglePlaces.h not found.

Without that I get a number of undeclared identifiers such as
[highlighted enumerateAttribute:kGMSAutocompleteMatchA

I have tried installing / updating pods. 
I have checked the paths

Tried the usual things but no luck. I'm hoping what is below might help someone help me....

```
#import "XLFormGooglePlacesAutoCompletePickerViewController.h"
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import <GooglePlaces/GooglePlaces.h>

@interface AddressModal : NSObject
@property(retain,nonatomic) NSAttributedString* text;
@end

@implementation AddressModal
+addressModalWithTitle: (NSAttributedString*)title
{
AddressModal* modal = [[self alloc] init];
if(modal){
    NSMutableAttributedString *highlighted = [title mutableCopy];
    [highlighted enumerateAttribute:kGMSAutocompleteMatchAttribute
                       inRange:NSMakeRange(0, highlighted.length)
                       options:0
                    usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
                        if(value){
                            [highlighted addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.9778 blue:0.5437 alpha:1.0] range:range];
                        }
                    }];
    modal.text = highlighted;
}
return modal;
}
@end
```

Deployment Target  12.2

XCode  10.3

```
pod 'UIActionSheet-Blocks'
pod 'GooglePlaces'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'GooglePlacePicker'
pod 'XLFormGooglePlacesAutoCompletePicker', :path => 'XLFormGooglePlacesAutoCompletePicker'
pod 'QRCodeReaderViewController'
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Latest version of GooglePlaces & GoogleMaps from the following links:   "https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/8a8ad90cc90f312f/GooglePlaces-3.3.0.tar.gz" "https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/97fb1c4023fbdb2b/GoogleMaps-3.3.0.tar.gz"
2. drag GoogleMapsBase.framework & GooglePlaces.framework into **your project's folder**
3. Add the frameworks to your target

Comment: Just to clarify, I currently have these set up as follows (GooglePlaces ad a example); 

 [project root] > Pods > GooglePlaces > Pods > Frameworks > GooglePlaces.framework

Are you saying it should be rather ; 

 [project root] >GooglePlaces.framework 

Cheers

Comment: @MarkAnderson if this the case, it supposed to work without changing anything. maybe your framework's location isn't relative to group?